# Does Conditional Convergence of a series imply that the series is an alternating series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I was discussing with a friend today and we stumbled upon this conjecture that we couldn't disprove. It's about that all series that are conditionally convergent are alternating series.

If $\sum a_n$ is conditionally convergent then $\exists b_k$ such that $\sum a_k = \sum (-1)^k b_k$ or $\sum a_k = \sum (-1)^{k+1} b_k$.

We weren't able to disprove it and I strongly believe that it is false. Help me disprove it.

Thank you.

Comment: What you are looking for is the core idea in the proof of the Riemann rearrangement theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem .

Comment: I don't see how that relates to my assumption. But it's an interesting read to see how any conditional convergent series can be rearranged to sum to any real number. Thats just not intuitive, any real number.

Comment: In the given link (see the section with the proof), your $b_k$  would be sums of either only positive or only negative members of the given series. This would lead to an alternating series which "oscillates" around a given number $M$.

Comment: Alternating series are simply the most common type of conditionally convergent series. Regarding the Riemann rearrangement theorem, perhaps even more interesting is that in several ways **most rearrangements** (in various senses) of a conditionally convergent series are about as non-divergent as you can imagine. See [this 19 September 2000 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/sci.math/_QAPMEknGiA/alStnJOqlq4J) and [this little known historical precursor](https://mathoverflow.net/a/345022/15780).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like...

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( a_n - a_{n+1} + b_n \right) $$

where $a_n \rightarrow 0$, $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are divergent and convergent respectively, and every *third* term is negative.

Comment: If we let $a_n = -n$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$. Since $\sum a_n - a_{n+1} + b_n$ converges, we can regroup and get $1 + b_1 + 1 + b_2 + 1 + b_3 + ... $ which doesn't converge. So would this work? But I see what you're saying about having every third term negative. That's a type of series that I was trying to construct, but failed to do so.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified $a_n \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: That works! Thanks for helping me find an example. I should've recalled the harmonic series for the $a_n$.

Comment: No problemo. One potential caveat however, is that we might worry about rearranging and regrouping causing the sum to oscillate / diverge to infinity, à la the Riemann rearrangement theorem. But someone else will have to worry about that...

Comment: Grouping shouldn't matter for conditional convergence, right? But rearrangement does matter